# Aurelia Karma Instanbul coverage error -4075

Tags: aurelia, istanbul, karma-coverage, remap-istanbul

I recently started to get the following error when running karma inside the Aurelia app:

```
ERROR [reporter.remap-istanbul]: { RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:923:18)
at sync (..\node_modules\karma-remap-istanbul\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:71:13)
at sync (..\node_modules\karma-remap-istanbul\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
at sync (..\node_modules\karma-remap-istanbul\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
at sync (..\node_modules\karma-remap-istanbul\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
at sync (..\node_modules\karma-remap-istanbul\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
at sync (..\node_modules\karma-remap-istanbul\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
at sync (..\node_modules\karma-remap-istanbul\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
at sync (..\node_modules\karma-remap-istanbul\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
at sync (..\node_modules\karma-remap-istanbul\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
at sync (..\node_modules\karma-remap-istanbul\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
at sync (..\node_modules\karma-remap-istanbul\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
at sync (..\node_modules\karma-remap-istanbul\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
at sync (..\node_modules\karma-remap-istanbul\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
at sync (..\node_modules\karma-remap-istanbul\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
at sync (..\node_modules\karma-remap-istanbul\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
errno: -4075,
code: 'EEXIST',
syscall: 'mkdir',
path: '\\jka-test\\coverage' }
```

After a couple of days of research I have no solution to this error. Maybe somebody came across this error and managed to fix it.

Thank you for your time.

Update

The problem seams to be related to typescript interface files, as the code coverage is used inside Aurelia app it runs against the "appbundle.js" where it compiles the typescript files into js. The error appears because there are no interfaces inside js and thus Istanbul can't cover the empty files that were generated. There should have been an clearer code error for this type of situation...

Comment: I suggested (based on the code `EEXIST`) that you create a file or folder, which already exists.

Comment: I though so to, so I deleted all the files and folders that are inside the coverage folder but I still get the same error. I also tryied removing the folder all together but still no luck.

Comment: I too am running into this issue current. Were you ever able to figure it out? @Mipod